# GD::Graph Bar Chart column values

Tags: perl, gd-graph

I am using the `GD::Graph` module.  I need to write the value to which the column corresponds above each column on my chart.  How should I do it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use GD::Graph::bars3d;

sub stringToDec {
    my $ustring = '';
    for my $char (split //, shift){
        if(ord($char)>127){
            $ustring .= "&#" . (unpack("U", $char)+848) . ";";
        } else {
            $ustring .= $char;
        }   
    }
    return $ustring;
}

my @time    = ('00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00'); 
my @site1   = (    80 ,     30 ,     15 ,     40 ,    250 ,    340 );

my @data = (\@time, \@site1);

my $graph = GD::Graph::bars3d->new(800, 300);

$graph->set_title_font('arial.ttf', 9);
$graph->set_y_label_font('arial.ttf', 9);
$graph->set_legend_font('arial.ttf', 9);

$graph->set(
    y_label     => 'Кол-во',
    title       => 'Кол-во подключенных по месяцам',
    dclrs       => [ ('green', 'blue') ],
    bar_spacing => 15,
) or warn $graph->error;

$graph->set_legend('LAN', 'Ч.сектор');
my $image = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;

print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
print $image->png;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GD::Graph](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph)

**Plotting data point values with the data point**

> Sometimes you will want to plot the value of a data point or bar above
>   the data point for clarity. GD::Graph allows you to control this in a
>   generic manner, or even down to the single point.

**show_values**

> Set this to 1 to display the value of each data point above the point
>   or bar itself. No effort is being made to ensure that there is enough
>   space for the text.

```
$graph->set(show_values => 1);
```

[image: bar plot]